# Gitlab - Project cannot be transferred, because tags are present in its container registry

Tags: git, gitlab

> Project cannot be transferred, because tags are present in its container registry

I am encountering the above error when I try to transfer my git repository to a group.

I have checked in `Repository/Tags` but there are none. I have also checked in CI/CD tabs and there's nothing outstanding there either. So I'm wondering what tags is it referring to.

I am currently using Netlify for my frontend hosting and Heroku for my backend hosting.

Could either of these be applying some tags that I can't see/find?

Is my only option to export the project?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Issue 33301](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/33301#note_130962418) mentions:

> the only way to move a project with containers in the registry is to first delete them all.

Meaning delete the container tags in the registry (not the repository or CI/CD)

- Navigate to sidebar menu `Package->Container Registry` on a project where Container registry is enabled
- Click on the button "Remove Tag"

([since GitLab 12.3, Sept. 2019](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15737), you can delete the tags you want)

Comment: FWIW, GitLab seems to queue a task to delete the tags which might not happen for a few minutes or hours. You have to wait until that task runs & completes and then try the move again. The Container Registry page will show that status.

Comment: @Nick Thank you for the feedback. So we have to be patient ;)

Answer (score 0):

Deploy -> Container registry -> Delete button to each container

Answer (score 0):

GitLab does not allow for this. I typically fork and archive the old project.

Given the fact that arbitrary many other projects possibly still depend on the existing images (same applies to packages), I actually think it would not be a good practice to move them all to another group.